# What is the exact meaning of the JPA @Entity annotation?

Tags: jpa, annotations, entity

I am studying JPA in Spring application and I have some doubts related to the **@Entity** annotation.

So I have a model class like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name= “T_CUSTOMER”)
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @Column(name=“cust_id”)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name=“first_name”)
    private String firstName;

    @Transient
    private User currentUser;

    ...........................
    ...........................
    ...........................
}
```

Ok, I know that the **@Entity** annotation is on the class level and it means that the fields of the object that are instances of this class are to be mapped to the field of the **T_CUSTOMER** database table.

But why in JPA it is mandatory to use **@Entity** annotation and I cannot only use the **@Table** annotation to map a model object to a specific database table? It have some other meaning\behavior that actually I am missing?

What am I missing? What is the exact meaning of the **@Entity** annotation?

Comment: The `@Table` annotation is optional. So how would JPA know a class is to mapped to be used in the ORM process if it's not present?

Comment: The @Entity is optional also, since you can define what classes are entities in orm.xml

Comment: Dear Neil. what if we are talking about class level annotations, and in this case @Entity is mandatory

Answer (score 69, accepted):

`@Entity` annotation defines that a class can be mapped to a table. And that is it, it is just a marker, like for example `Serializable` interface.

And why `@Entity` annotation is mandatory? ... well, it is the way how JPA is designed. When you create a new entity you have to do at least two things

1. annotated it with `@Entity`
2. create an id field and annotate it with `@Id`

Anything else is optional, for example table name is derived from entity class name (and therefore `@Table` annotation can be optional), table's columns are derived from entities variables (and therefore `@Column` annotation can be optional), and so on ...

JPA is trying to provide a fast and easy start to developers who want to learn/use this API, and giving developers option to configure as few things as possible to make something functional is one of the ways how this API wants to achieve this "easy to use/learn" goal. Hence the `@Entity` annotation (together with `@Id` annotation) is the minimum you have to do in order to create an entity.

Comment: If "@Entity annotation defines that a class can be mapped to a table", why didn't they just use @Table !? Would be much clearer!

Comment: @IanVaughan Could be that this also shall support entities that are stored in a data store, which doesn't know tables, e.g. some nosql key-value stores?

Answer (score 2):

Entities in JPA are nothing but POJOs representing data that can be persisted to the database. An entity represents a table stored in a database. Every instance of an entity represents a row in the table.

More about the entities:
https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entities

Comment: Good quote from the website link.

Answer (score 0):

Entities represent persistent data stored in a relational database automatically using container-managed persistence.They are persistent because their data is stored persistently in some form of data storage system, such as a database: they do survive a server failure, failover, or a network failure. When an entity is reinstantiated, the state of the previous instance is automatically restored.

An entity models a business entity or multiple actions within a single business process. Entities are often used to facilitate business services that involve data and computations on that data. For example, you might implement an entity to retrieve and perform computation on items within a purchase order. Your entity can manage multiple, dependent, persistent objects in performing its tasks.

Entities can represent fine-grained persistent objects, because they are not remotely accessible components.

An entity can aggregate objects together and effectively persist data and related objects using the transactional, security, and concurrency services of a JPA persistence provider.

Answer (score 0):

We annotate the class with `@Entity` so that it can be included in the persistence unit.
We do this because the "persistence context" only manages the instances of those set of classes that are contained within the persistence unit.

In case of `persistence.xml`, we include the class in the persistence unit by the use of `<class>` tag.  Additionally, If we make use of `<exclude-unlisted-classes>` tag and set it to `false`, the persistence unit will then automatically scan for `@Entity` class and we don't need to specify it within `<class>` tag.

If we don't annotate the class with `@Entity`, it can't be included in the persistence unit.
Hope It helps :).